# Django ORM Issue: Same Query Set on 2 different views runs as drastically different speeds

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

I have Two views--one part of the admin site, and the other a publicly accessible view.

They both perform the same set of queries--literally copy and pasted code.

```
masterQuery = myObject.objects.filter(is_public=True)
newQuery =  queriedForms.filter(ref_to_parent_form__record_reference__form_name__icontains=term['TVAL'], ref_to_parent_form__record_reference_type__pk=rtypePK)
newQuery = newQuery.filter(flagged_for_deletion=False)
term['count'] =  newQuery.count()
masterQuery = (newQuery & masterQuery)
singleQueryStats['intersections'] = masterQuery.count()
```

Each view has this exact same code--it's not the prettiest query--but regardless: On the admin view--this runs in less than like a 1/4 second. On the public Views.py view--it takes 8 minutes. I cannot figure out why. The   queryset.query output is the same. The variables(admin submitted through POST/Public submitted through GET) also match.

EDITS: I tried simplifying things further to no avail:

```
SELECT `maqluengine_form`.`id`, `maqluengine_form`.`form_name`, `maqluengine_form`.`form_number`, `maqluengine_form`.`form_geojson_string`, `maqluengine_form`.`hierarchy_parent_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`is_public`, `maqluengine_form`.`project_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`date_created`, `maqluengine_form`.`created_by_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`date_last_modified`, `maqluengine_form`.`modified_by_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`sort_index`, `maqluengine_form`.`form_type_id`, `maqluengine_form`.`flagged_for_deletion` FROM `maqluengine_form` WHERE (`maqluengine_form`.`form_type_id` = 319 AND `maqluengine_form`.`flagged_for_deletion` = False)
```

this is the query output on both views--the admin view takes <1/4 second and the public view takes about 4-8 minutes depending to perform a count() operation on this queryset

There is no logic that could be changing the time--the timer server error log prints match up until the count is performed.

Neither queryset is evaluated before the count--just built. Still at an utter loss here.

Comment: Are you sure it is the *query* itself? Not logic *around* the query. Furthermore `QuerySet`s itself are *lazy*, so by writing queries, it does *not* per se mean these are *all* evaluated.

Comment: Yeah - there is simply no way that the query itself, if it's exactly the same and executed in exactly the same way, is slower in the Django admin.

Comment: In a minute I'll try seeing if I'm accidentally cacheing the query in the admin view before hand--which in theory is making it running faster.

I agree with the logistical absurdity of this though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being an idiot--the two querysets weren't the same--there was an additional booleanfield being hit, and I was reading the logs wrong--The answer is that the querysets WERE NOT the same--so that answers this.

I submitted a new question to figure out the drastic speed difference between the two.